# Jquery - Using this Selector

Tags: jquery

the following jquery work fine when I try it:

```
var memberPhoto = $('img.memberPhoto');
memberPhoto.hover(function() {
     $('div.memberBackDrop').toggle();
});
```

However when I to use the `this` selector it doesn't work - like below.

```
$(this,'div.memberBackDrop').toggle();
```

what is the correct way to use this in this case?

---

HTML Code below (part of):

```
<table id="memberPhotos"><tr>
<td><img src="images/online-dating-main/poll-pic1.jpg" class="shadowMild memberPhoto">
<div class="memberBackDrop">
  <h6 class="memberUserName">Summertime09</h6>
  <h6>37, Male</h6>
  <h6>Melbourne</h6>
  <h6>Australia</h6>
</div></td>

<td><img src="images/online-dating-main/poll-pic1.jpg" class="shadowMild memberPhoto">
<div class="memberBackDrop">
  <h6 class="memberUserName">Summertime09</h6>
  <h6>37, Male</h6>
  <h6>Melbourne</h6>
  <h6>Australia</h6>
</div></td>

<td><img src="images/online-dating-main/poll-pic1.jpg" class="shadowMild memberPhoto">
<div class="memberBackDrop">
  <h6 class="memberUserName">Summertime09</h6>
  <h6>37, Male</h6>
  <h6>Melbourne</h6>
  <h6>Australia</h6>
</div></td>
```

Comment: `$(this,'div.memberBackDrop')` theoretically means: Select the element `this` refers to, inside `div.memberBackDrop`. This does not make sense, since you already have a reference to the element, namely `this`. What are you actually trying to do? Do you want to **find** `div.memberBackDrop` which is a descendant of `this`?

Comment: you want to toggle the div.memberBackDrop

Comment: yes I want to  find div.memberBackDrop which is a descendant of this? there are many div.memberBackDrop and I just want the current one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.memberBackDrop` is not a descendant of the image, it is a sibling. In this case you want to use [`.siblings` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```
$(this).siblings('div.memberBackDrop').toggle();
```

Make sure to have a look at the other [*tree-traversal methods*](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) which come in handy when you already have a reference to an element.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is not a selector. `this` is an object. In jQuery, jQuery(this) will normally point to the object representing the currently selected element.

### Please use `$('div.memberBackDrop').toggle()` instead.

Edit

Please change your like this,

```
jQuery('img.memberPhoto')
    .hover(function() {
    jQuery(this).siblings('div.memberBackDrop').toggle();
});
```

You have to select the `[sibling][1]` div of your image tag.

Comment: added the HTML - the first part of it but should be enough to show... I get the hover to work fine but I just want to select the current $('div.memberBackDrop')